# My Jquery datepicker NOT working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!doctype html> 
    <html lang="en"> 
       <head> 
          <meta charset="utf-8"> 
          <script  src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
          <script type="text/javascript"> 
             $(document).ready(function() { 
                $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(); 
             }); 
          </script> 
       </head> 
       <body> 
          <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p> 
       </body>
    </html>
```

My code is not working .when i click my input box that time the onclick calender not appear.I think there may be use onclick() function .But i can not . Please help me. :(

Comment: 1. Are you sure you have jquery-ui loaded (note: **not just jquery**)? 2. What does the error console say? 3. Are you sure $('#datepicker') is resolved to an element?

Comment: You need to add a reference to jquery-ui. The datepicker control is not included in the base jquery distro.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/o03prz06/

Comment: Be graceful to new player. We were all once there, guys. Stop down voting, plz.

Comment: Lurk moar. Read the rules before posting. Read documentation and take Debugger 101 before assuming you can't solve a problem for yourself. *We all did this at one point.*

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example and look at the script needed include both jQuery and jQuery-ui. (source: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_datepicker.htm)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Datepicker functionality</title>
      <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <!-- Javascript -->
      <script>
         $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker-13" ).datepicker();
            $( "#datepicker-13" ).datepicker("show");
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- HTML --> 
      <p>Enter Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker-13"></p>
   </body>
</html>
```